# How to set multiple checkboxes in one merged cell?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidgetitem

I need to set multiple checkboxes in one merged cell in order to have them side by side or one under another (doesn't matter). Now they overlap each other when I try.

Here the piece from the code:

```
QTableWidget* my_table;
...
my_table->setSpan(0, 2, 2, 2);
...
my_table->setCellWidget(0,2, new QCheckBox("First"));
my_table->setCellWidget(1,2, new QCheckBox("Second"));
```

[image]

Comment: You need a `QHBoxLayout` or `QVBoxLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a QWidget with a layout (horizontal or vertical), and then add the checkboxes to the layout, something like this:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
QCheckBox *cb = new QCheckBox(widget);
cb->setText("First");
QCheckBox *cb2 = new QCheckBox(widget);
cb2->setText("Second");
widget ->layout()->addWidget(cb); //adding to layout the first checkbox
widget ->layout()->addWidget(cb2);//adding to layout the second checkbox

//Your code
my_table->setCellWidget(1,2, widget);
```

Comment: I followed @Xatyrian's advise and it worked. My code looks bit different but the principle is the same. Thanks.